# Why is an argument passed to a Perl script not working on running it from within a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a batch called `pippo.bat` for launching a program with an argument. However, it fails in getting such argument. In other words, it acts as I don't give it any argument.

**pippo.bat**

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=150 lines=5000
title Link Setting
echo.
echo                         LINK SETTING
echo.
cd /d E:\Program Files (x86)\pippo\bin
pippoedit.ovpl –f C:\Work\pippo.xml
pause
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What argument are you providing, and what is the batch supposed to do with the argument?

Comment: The argument of -f option is C:\Work\pippo.xml and this is the name of the fiel to be parsed by the OVPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing `pippoedit.ovpl –f C:\Work\pippo.xml`.

Note the extension, `.ovpl`, which isn't registered as an executable. This means you let the OS figure out and start the application associated with that extension, and start that program with that filename as argument. Here, a small repro:

```
@echo off
foo.txt bar.txt
```

This starts Notepad or whichever application is associated with the `.txt` extension and displays the file `foo.txt`.

When you do this, Windows doesn't do anything with the arguments beyond the first. Instead you should start the application directly, and pass it the arguments:

```
pippoedit.exe pippoedit.ovpl –f C:\Work\pippo.xml
```

Or whatever the executable is called.

Comment: Since .ovpl it is a PERL script, should I launch it with
perl pippoedit.ovpl –f C:\Work\pippo.xml?

Comment: I don't know how to pass arguments to a Perl script, rather than to the Perl executable, but I'm sure that's documented somewhere.

Comment: Note that the behaviour depends on the way the application sets up the file association.  It *can* pass the arguments if it wants to.  In this case it probably should, the fact that it doesn't may be a bug in Perl.

Comment: @Harry have a link for that? I remember something about %1 %2 %3 and so on in associations, but couldn't find it. A small repro with a "default" registration (create new file extension, associate with a program that only prints its commandline arguments) only printed the first filename.

Comment: The only reference I could find was the [documentation for ftype](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771394(v=ws.11).aspx) which is kind of unsatisfactory.  But there are examples in the built-in file types, e.g., a shortcut to a batch file, when double-clicked, will run the batch file with whatever arguments are specified in the shortcut.  If you then change the "open" verb for batfile from the default value `"%1" %*` to just `"%1"` and double-click the shortcut again, the arguments are ignored.

Comment: That should work the same way in your repro, presumably you set the command to something like `myapp.exe "%1"` which will only pass the name of the file, if you instead use `myapp.exe "%1" %*` you should get the arguments as well.